# Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a program and when I run it I get the following error:

```
'Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x0000023F5EEF4CF8>
```

I don't know how to solve it and whether it is my problem or external to me.
The problem appears on line 132 and I only have 74 lines written :(

```
Python version: 3.6.0
Tensorflow version: 2.6.2
Keras version: 2.6.0
```

Libraries:

```
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import  Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

Last lines of code before it displays the error:

```
cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtconv1, siz_filtconv1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=siz_pool))
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtconv2, siz_filtconv2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=siz_pool))
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtconv3, siz_filtconv3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=siz_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(classs, activation='softmax'))
print('1')
optim=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
print('2')
cnn.compile(optimizer=optim,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
print('3')
```

Output when I run:

```
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "NeuronalRed.py", line 63, in <module>
cnn.compile(optimizer=optim,loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 573, in compile
self.optimizer = self._get_optimizer(optimizer)
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 611, in _get_optimizer
return nest.map_structure(_get_single_optimizer, optimizer)
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 869, in map_structure
structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 869, in <listcomp>
structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 602, in _get_single_optimizer
opt = optimizers.get(opt)
File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 132, in get
'Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x000001805F30F2E8>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.SGD object at 0x0000013887021208>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272318/valueerror-could-not-interpret-optimizer-identifier-tensorflow-python-keras-o) or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056356/could-not-interpret-optimizer-identifier-error-in-keras

Comment: But I don't use SGD I use Adam, I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: You are mixing the use of tf.keras and keras, note that you are using tensorflow.keras imports yet the error points to a keras optimizer (not a tf.keras one).

Comment: I'm a bit confused with tf.keras and keras, I understand what it says but I don't know what I should change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.python` from each imported libraries as below:

```
import os
import tensorflow  # also import tensorflow individually
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

After this try again executing your entire code and let us know if issue still persists.